# How to set max number of simultaneous users sessions per role

Tags: oracle, session, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to restrict the max number of connected users with the same role on oracle. I just figured out how to restric max sessions per user with:
    SESSIONS_PER_USERS

But i have problems restricting max sessions per role.

PS. This is my first question, sorry if the structure isn't rigth. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I want to restrict the max number of connected users with the same role on oracle."

This can't be done. There are a number of complexities with roles.

1. Roles can be enabled or disabled. Should sessions where the user has the role disabled count towards the total number of sessions? If 'yes' then that means treating roles differently in this context. If 'no' then users can work around the limits.
2. Users can have many roles. What would happen if one of their roles breaches its limit but the others are fine?
3. Users who hit the `sessions_per_user` limit know what has happened and are in a position to handle it. Users who hit a notional `sessions_per_role` limit may have no idea what the other sessions are, and no recourse but to contact the help desk.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding you need to configure through the user profile, which can limit sessions_per_user.

```
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6010.htm
```

Comment: This shows how to limit *sessions per user*, The OP has told us they already know how to do this.